# DatePicker Validation Jquery How to Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, datepicker

I have one Datepicker and because of users may write invalid characters to textbox, i want to have datepicker validation.

Here is my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.TextBox("txtDate", txtDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "date", id = "txtDate" })
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Getir" />

}
```

First question:
My date comes like "dd.MM.yyyy" but in this script code it comes like "mm/dd/yyyy". How can i format this script code like "dd.MM.yyyy"?

Second question:
If my date validation is false how can i disable button click to submit?

Here is the script code and [its link.](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2011/12/validate-date-using-jquery.html)

```
 $(function() {
    $('#btnSubmit').bind('click', function(){
        var txtVal =  $('#txtDate').val();
        if(isDate(txtVal))
            alert('Valid Date');
        else
            alert('Invalid Date');
    });

function isDate(txtDate)
{
    var currVal = txtDate;
    if(currVal == '')
        return false;

    var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/; //Declare Regex
    var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?

    if (dtArray == null) 
        return false;

    //Checks for mm/dd/yyyy format.
    dtMonth = dtArray[1];
    dtDay= dtArray[3];
    dtYear = dtArray[5];        

    if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12) 
        return false;
    else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay> 31) 
        return false;
    else if ((dtMonth==4 || dtMonth==6 || dtMonth==9 || dtMonth==11) && dtDay ==31) 
        return false;
    else if (dtMonth == 2) 
    {
        var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
        if (dtDay> 29 || (dtDay ==29 && !isleap)) 
                return false;
    }
    return true;
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question. Change the rxDatePattern variable in the script to:

```
var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\.|-)(\d{1,2})(\.|-)(\d{4})$/; //Declare Regex
```

Notice how I replaced the slash with the dots.

Then I would recommend you to have the button disabled by default and enable it when a valid date is in the datefield textbox. So I would change the `$('#btnSubmit').bind('click')` function to:

```
$('#txtDate').on('keyup', function(){
    var txtVal =  $('#txtDate').val();
    if(isDate(txtVal))
        $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
    else
        $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EywSP/1729/)

**EDIT:**

My bad, I misunderstood. Tought somehow you were asking for mm.dd.yyyy format.

But I've made some changes to my original code. With the same html I changed the jQuery a bit:

```
function isDate(txtDate)
{
    //Here comes one ugly, long and working regexp
    var rxDatePattern = /^(((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(0?[13578]|1[02])\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\.(0?[13456789]|1[012])\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\.0?2\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\.0?2\.((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0?[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g;

    return txtDate.match(rxDatePattern); //Returns true iff. currval is a valid date
};
function validate_datePicker(){
    var txtVal =  $('#txtDate').val();
    if(isDate(txtVal))
        $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);        
    else
        $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtDate').on('keyup', function(){
        validate_datePicker();
    });
    validate_datePicker();
});
```

Checkout the new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EywSP/1734/)

The regexp evaluates wether a given date string is a date or not. Notice that it is both valid to have the date 08.08.2014 and 8.8.2014. (That is the zero in front of the date and month are optional)

Comment: thank you for your answer but i can still click the button when type is wrong.

my date-type is: {0:dd.MM.yyyy}

i am trying to convert yours like that:

  dtDay = dtArray[1];
            dtMonth = dtArray[3];
            dtYear = dtArray[5];

is it true?

Comment: And my txtDate value comes from controller like that: 

txtDate = {14.8.2014 19:27:26}. any idea?

Comment: i solved date-type problems. 

when i try to set value to my datepicker(true format) button still doesnt work.

when i type with hand button works.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works great. But when i choose date with my datepicker and set its value to textboxt, button still not active but when i type numbers to textbox everything is quite ok.

so button doesnt recognize datepicker selected value.

i'll use your codes another project. my solution is i make date textbox readonly and find a jquery datepicker with month,year and day options.

Comment: Yes try changing the "$('#txtDate').on('keyup', function(){" part to "$('#event_ends_at').on('keyup change paste input changeDate', function(){" in the document.ready function. Does that work?

Comment: sorry, i was a bit busy. i'll check it out.